# Unit-tests for preprocessor macros for cross-compilation and CMake

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake, c-preprocessor

Our project builds with CMake on several platforms, including Windows, Linux and cross-compilation on some embedded OSes, described with custom CMake toolchain files.

In case of cross-compilation, we have to maintain sets of preprocessor macros.

It is reflected in `CMakeLists.txt` in the following fashion.

File `embedded_os1.toolchain.cmake`

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR ARM)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /path/to/cross-compiler)

# blah-blah-blah

set(embedded_OS1 TRUE)
```

... and we have similar files for other embedded OSes.

File `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)

if(embedded_OS1)
    add_definitions(-Dmacro1 -Dmacro2)
elseif(embedded_OS2)
    add_definitions(-Dmacro3 -Dmacro4)
elseif(embedded_OS3)
    add_definitions(-Dmacro1 -Dmacro4)
endif()
```

I'd like to perform some kind of automatic checking that all preprocessor macros are set correctly.

I can easily do it with unit-tests on Windows and Linux.

But there is no possibility to compile and run executable files on embedded OSes, I can compile only static libs, that are then signed, put in a firmware images, etc, etc. And all I have on PC besides library is the JSON file with compiler calls, generated by `EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`.

What could you suggest?

Comment: `is no possibility to compile on embedded OSes` ? There surely is a possibility to compile, otherwise it all would be pointless. Usually each OS defines some macro, like `__WIN__` or `__LINUX__` or `__ZEPHYR__` that can be used in code, there is usually no need for putting it in cmake.

Comment: I mean "easily compile and run executable file". Only static library. It then has to be signed, put in a firmware image, etc... I don't know all details. Also the PC doesn't always have connected device.

Comment: `Only static library` But surelly you _can compile_. If so `#if defined embedded_OS1 && ( ! defined macro1 || ! defined macro2 ) #error "You have to define macro1 and macro2 for embeddedOS1"` you can write preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it with `#warning` macro and check the compilation output with bash of whatever. Then you can set `Werror` for these files and get compile-time check. Or simply use `#error` (thanks to KamilCuk)

Another way is to dig into check binaries that help to see if the toolchain has threading or something else.